# Usage of sparse matrices in R

Tags: r, sparse-matrix

I'm writing an R code, where is generated a big sparse matrix that I have to use to solve a linear system.

Actually, matrix is singular, so I can't solve the problem. I suspect that this can be avoided using a good way to store the sparse matrix.

So I'd like to use C++ `eigen` library, where usage of sparse matrix should be efficient. But how can I pass the matrix and solve the system in a C++ code? How can I use this `eigen` library in R?

Comment: What is the question, how to create a spare matrix, or how to create a sparse matrix using C++ library?

Comment: How to create a C++ sparse matrix in R